# Uncaught ReferenceError: kpoejy is not defined

Tags: plugin-development, javascript

i am trying to add keyup function in wordpress so email address is directly populated from blog admin and when users type/edit the email address the corresponding link gets updated accordingly.

Here is my code

```
<input name="pluginemail" type="text" id="pluginemail" value="'.get_bloginfo('admin_email').' " onchange="kpoejy.updateSignupEmail();"> <a type="button" id="request_key" class="button button-primary" title="Request a new API key" href="http://somesitess.com/g11.php?pluginemail='.get_bloginfo('admin_email').'" onmouseenter="kpoejy.updateSignupEmail();" target="_blank">Request Key</a>
```

here is javascript in external file named javascr.js

```
 var kpoejy= function() {
   function updateSignupEmail() {
        jQuery('#request_key').attr('href', jQuery('#request_key').attr('href').split('?')[0] + '?pluginemail=' + jQuery('#pluginemail').val());
    }}
```

this is included using

```
    wp_register_script( 'javas-js', plugins_url( '/js/dist/javascr.misc.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
```

i tried `wp_localize_script`, `wp_enqueue_script` also but getting always same error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: kpoejy is not defined

any idea where i am doing mistake. its for wordpress 4.8

Comment: Please provide the complete error message. Usually, the error message will tell you the file the variable was used. You can use that info as a clue to looking for the issue.

Comment: As Rick Hellewell already said, please update the question with more infos. Especially: How and where are you enqueuing? Can you see that the file is successfully loaded via network tab in the developer console?

Answer (score 0):

You're not properly defining the JS object. The following will work

```
var kpoejy = {
        updateSignupEmail: function() {
            // code
        }
    };
```

Because now you're making `kpoejy` an object (via `{}`) and inside assign the key `updateSignupEmail` a function.

What you did previously was to assign `kpoejy` a function, and inside that define another function.